# Why there are same node in path in my query in neo4j?

Tags: python-2.7, time, neo4j, py2neo

There is cypher sql like this：

```
match p=(:Devices{name:"123.123.123.123"})-[r:Cost*..6]->(:Devices{name:"123.123.123.124"}) with p return p;
```

Then it's return：

```
{u'p': (123.123.123.123)-[:Cost {Cost: 21}]->(123.123.123.120)-[:Cost {Cost: 92}]->(123.123.123.110)-[:Cost {Cost: 82}]->(123.123.123.119)-[:Cost {Cost: 91}]->(123.123.123.123)-[:Cost {Cost: 56}]->(123.123.123.130)-[:Cost {Cost: 24}]->(123.123.123.124)}
```

There is a ring in my path and how to avoid this condition.

Finally why my query is so solw and query
a path under in 10 depth will spend about 1000s-2500s.

There is my config:

```
dbms.memory.heap.initial_size=4096m
dbms.memory.heap.max_size=9192m
dbms.memory.pagecache.size=10g
dbms.threads.worker_count=16
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you meant to specify a path of between 1 and 6 hops, rather than exactly six:

```
match p=(:Devices{name:"123.123.123.123"})-[r:Cost*1..6]->
  (:Devices{name:"123.123.123.124"}) with p return p;
```

Comment: Thanks,but there also will spend many time in select path and get result.How to let select be fastly?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question please? I did not understand the meaning. Do you mean you want the query to return faster? Is there an index on `:Device` name property?

Comment: Yes，I want the query to return faster.Now I query a path  will spend about 1000s if the max hops is 10。

Comment: One specific question at a time please. If the first answer solved your initial question, can you accept the answer, an open a new question with regards to increasing performance. Post a link in the comment.

Comment: Ok，thanks  for your suggestions！I meant a path every node only  have one and avoid the ring.Doest't like this：  {u'p': (123.123.123.123)-[:Cost {Cost: 21}]->(123.123.123.120)-[:Cost {Cost: 92}]->(123.123.123.123)->